# Paste a formula in numbers 4.2 without altering format of recipient cell

Tags: ios, ipad, numbers

How do i paste a formula in numbers 4.2 without altering format of the target cell? I’m sure this used to be easy, but can't seem to do it.

I want to paste a formula from a colour filled cell to a column of different colour filled cells without changing the colour formatting of those cells (all on the same spreadsheet).

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) Can I ask you to [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/344369/edit) your question to provide additional details? For example, what are you pasting the formula from (e.g. from somewhere else within Numbers, from Excel, etc)? Also, can you explain **how** you're currently trying to do it, just so people don't suggest what you've already tried.  Also adding the version of iOS installed may be relevant.